# Multiple inputs on a single mapper in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce, mapper

I'm developing an algorithm that needs to run two sequential mapreduce jobs, where the second one takes in input the input and the output of the first one at the same time. I found four ways to do it and I want to know witch of these is the most efficient or if there are other methods.

**Distributed Cache**

Merging all the reducer output into a single file and loading it on Distributed Cache

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(confi);

    Path pt = new Path(output.toString() + "/out.txt");
    try{
        FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(output);
        BufferedWriter brOut=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(pt,true)));

        for (int i=0;i<status.length;i++){

            BufferedReader brIn=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(status[i].getPath())));
            String line;
            line=brIn.readLine();

            while (line != null){
                brOut.write(line + "\n");
                line=brIn.readLine();
            }
        }
        brOut.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    job.addCacheFile(pt.toUri());
```

**Adding it as a resource to the configuration class**

As before I merge the output saving it on a String and than:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.setStrings("input2ndjob", outputFromReducer);
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf,"Second Job");
```

**Reading from hdfs**

The second map reads the output files of first reducers directly from hdfs

**Passing two values as input**

I have found on [this](http://importantfish.com/limited-pass-algorithms/) webpage this pseudocode where it seems that they are passing two arguments as input to the second mapper but I don't know how to do that.

```
map(key, value):
    // value is the candidate itemsets and a chunk of the full dataset
    Count occurrences of itemsets in the chunk.
    for itemset in itemsets:
        emit(itemset, supp(itemset))

reduce(key, values):
    result = 0
    for value in values:
        result += value
    if result >= s:
        emit(key, result)
```

Comment: What you have described is what Oozie was designed to do. Any particular reason why you want to do this in code?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use Oozie because I haven't the rights to install it on the production environment.

Comment: That is _annoying_! In that case I'd go with **Reading from hdfs** because then that's how I'd expect a MapReduce job to work. That said, **Adding it as a resource to the configuration class**, and **Passing two values as input** should also work, but strike we as a weird way to handle the problem. Finally, I'd avoid using the **Distributed Cache** for this.

Comment: Can you explain why do you suggest me to avoid distributed cache? Thank you

Comment: Sure! The short answer is you wouldn't use the distributed cache because that's not what the distributed cache is for!

The longer answer is that using the Distributed Cache as a datastore will cause problems with Hadoop's code to data model. The Distributed Cache is intended to deliver static files to which ever nodes in the cluster need them. In my experience this mostly means library Jars and such. This would cause a lot of network problems if what we are sending around is a 2Gb result set.

Comment: The goal is to share the reducer's outputs of "phase I" with all nodes. The second mappers elaborate the data of the first input maps on the basis of the shared data elaborated into the phase I. The size of first reducer's outputs is strictly less of 2Gb.

Comment: If the need is to share a relatively small file with (potentially) every node, then using Distributed Cache would do that for you. That said, the sharing requirement strikes me as a bit unusual. But if that's what you need, that's what you need.